# Подключение файла к дочерней странице

Tags: php

У меня есть корневая папка. В ней лежит папка "blocks" в которой находится head.php. Этот файл подключается ко всем остальным через PHP:

```
require_once "blocks/head.php"
```

Но он подключается только к тем файлам, которые находятся в той же папке (в папке где находится папка blocks). Если создать другую папку, например: "Other Pages" и поместить туда другой файл, то подключить к нему просто так файл head.php не получится. Я не знаю как это сделать. Подскажите. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А откуда вы знаете что файл подключается ко всем остальным?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Файл надо подключать командой

```
require_once $_SEVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/blocks/head.php"
```

тогда он будет подключаться отовсюду.

А на досуге надо почитать про [абсолютные и относительные пути](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths).

Comment: Спасибо что уделили время на такой глупый вопрос. Очень вам благодарен

Answer (score 2):

Используйте для указания пути к подключаемым файлам суперглобальный масив `$_SERVER`, в частности его элемент `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` содержит путь к корневой директории где размещен Ваш проект.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "blocks/head.php");
```

Comment: Спасибо всё работает